# Is there any data structure which can avoid duplication, preserve order and random access

Tags: java, python, collections

Previously, while I am looking for the data structure with the following characteristic.

- Avoid duplication
- Iteration order will be same as insertion order

**In Java, I use [LinkHashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), In Python, I use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)**

Now, on the top of 2 requirements, I would like to have an additional requirement

- Able to random access through indexing, means I can access through `data[123]`

Is there any data structure available? Or I need to fall back to use `List`? `List` able to full fill 2nd and 3rd requirement, but not 1st. I may need to perform manual (and slow check) during insertion, to avoid duplication?

Comment: Why did [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142406/how-to-have-data-structure-with-both-tuple-and-dictionary-characteristic/4145109#4145109) to your question addressing precisely this topic in python not work?

Comment: @aaronasterling: He *seems* to be asking for an appropriate data structure, not about any particular existing class implementing this (none exists in Python's standard library that I know of).

Comment: @aaronasterling : I know it don't work. I just want know, any standard library available in the market.

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK I undeleted my answer to your previous question. It has an implementation of what you're looking for in Python. I don't think that there's a preexisting, named data structure to do what you want.

Comment: So you want it to do the same as `data.items()[123]` ?

Comment: What you're talking about is a "unique list". Out of the 4 general types of collections you can have ("list", "set", "multiset" and "unique list") it's the least useful by far. I think they were at one time considering putting a `UniqueList` in Google Collections/Guava but it seems like they've decided not to, or just not bothered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach in Java would be to create a wrapper class that implements both the `Set` and `List` interfaces, and that contained both a `HashSet` and `ArrayList`.  Update operations would need to update both internal collections, and read operations would be mapped to whichever internal collection gives the correct semantics and best performance.  The only slightly tricky method is `iterator()` where you need to arrange that `remove` updates both collections.

This approach will give you the "best of both worlds" performance for read operations, but updates will necessarily be slower.  In particular, insert at a given position and remove will be `O(N)` operations.

(I'd note that LinkedHashSet is not a direct solution since it does not provide a `get(int)` method.  You could implement this method via the LinkedHashSet iterator, by that makes it an `O(N)` operation.  Probably not what you want.)

**FOLLOW UP**

I've not been able to find a general purpose implementation class that implements both the `Set` and `List` interfaces.  I think that the reason is that there are semantic anomalies when you combine the interfaces.  For example, (as @ColinD notes) if you call `E set(int, E)` with an element that it already in the list, it is not clear what the result should be.  Dealing with this in a way that satisfies everyone is probably impossible, and I can understand why they might have decided not to go swimming in the tarpit.

However, I don't see this as a major problem if you are creating a `Set` + `List` class for your application's internal use.  You either

- pick a semantic for that suits your application,
- code your application to not use the method at all, or
- code your application to avoid being bitten by the anomaly.

(For instance, you might code it to either ignore result of the `set` method, to throw an unchecked exception if there is a duplicate, or return `null` or some distinguished object if there is a duplicate.)

For the record, it is not unforgivable for a custom collection class to violate the interface contract.  Indeed, even the Java designers do it - see IdentityHashMap.  What is unforgivable is not documenting the contract violations in the javadocs.

Comment: @Stephen C : Any standard library available? I prefer not to create my own.

Comment: I am not aware of any, but you could check the usual places: Apache Commons Collections, and Google Collections.  The problem is that your requirements are hard to meet in an efficient way.  Most people rework their algorithms to avoid this particular combination.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd implement `List` or `Set` for such a data structure since it differs a bit from the expectations for each of those.

Comment: @ColinD - the `List` spec says: "Unlike sets, lists **typically** allow duplicate elements.".  IMO, that means it is OK for a special purpose `List` to not allow duplicates.

Comment: @Stephen: Possibly, though I think it could lead to significant confusion to have a `List` and call `add` on it and have nothing happen. Certain `List` method semantics don't work well with the possibility of not being able to put an element in. For example, if you call `E set(int index, E element)` with an element that's already in the unique list, what does it return? The only options are: the element you gave it, the element already at index even though it wasn't removed, and `null`, which could be a valid element in the list. None of these options make sense, making this all problematic.

Comment: You cannot implement both List and Set in the same class, as they have conflicting contractual requirements for several methods (add, equals, hashCode...)

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion - see the followup part my answer for a rebuttal.  Basically, you **can** break contractual requirements, and sometimes it is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use an immutable collection, use an ImmutableSet from Guava, which has an asList() view to provide indexed access.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Set`  doesn't provide random access methods like get() and set(), so most/all of its implementations don't either. You could create your own implementation of `Set` that will provide this, maybe with an ArrayList to hold the data.

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedHashSet class provides the toArray-Method, which should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to find a basic data structure that does this; the goals you're looking for rule out all of them.  You might find an more esoteric one that'll do it, but the easiest approach is to use a compound data structure, maintaining two data structures in parallel.

That's what `collections.OrderedDict` does under the hood, in fact.  That's not what you want, though: since it's not designed to support indexing, it uses a linked list under the hood for preserving order.  Linked lists can't do indexing--short of a slow, linear scan, which you usually want to avoid since it tends to turn O(n^2) on you if used in a loop.

Here's a simple implementation.  It maintains two data structures: a list, preserving the order of items as they're set, and a dict, for quick lookup by key.  Both hold the value, and both hold the other's key: the dict holds the index within the list, and the list holds the key within the dict.  This makes it easy to reference each data structure from the other, so it can handle both assignment and iteration efficiently.

Note that this doesn't implement every operation, just the basic ones: dict-style assignment `a['x'] = 1`, dict-style lookup `a['x']`, list-style assignment `a.set_value_by_index(0, 1)` and list-style lookup `a.get_value_by_index(0)`.

Also note carefully: this doesn't use the same syntax for dict-style and list-style operations.  That's confusing and evil, and will bite you badly sooner or later.  This doesn't turn `a[0]` into a list-style lookup; if that's what you want, be explicit and use `get_value_by_index`.  Don't be *magic* and try to guess based on the parameter type.

Finally, it provides simple dict-style iteration, yielding the keys as a dict does.  Implementing things like `iteritems` and `itervalues` or Python3 views are obvious extensions.

```
class IndexableUniqueList(object):
    """
    >>> a = IndexableUniqueList()
    >>> a['x'] = 1
    >>> a['x']
    1
    >>> a['y'] = 2
    >>> a['y']
    2
    >>> a.get_key_by_index(0)
    'x'
    >>> a.get_value_by_index(0)
    1
    >>> a.get_key_by_index(1)
    'y'
    >>> a.get_value_by_index(1)
    2
    >>> a['x'] = 3
    >>> a.get_key_by_index(0)
    'x'
    >>> a.get_value_by_index(0)
    3
    >>> a.set_value_by_index(0, 4)
    >>> a['x']
    4
    >>> [val for val in a]
    ['x', 'y']
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.items_by_index = []
        self.items_by_key = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.items_by_key[key][1]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.items_by_key:
            idx, old_value = self.items_by_key[key]
            self.items_by_key[key] = (idx, value)
            self.items_by_index[idx] = (key, value)
            return

        idx = len(self.items_by_index)
        self.items_by_key[key] = (idx, value)
        self.items_by_index.append((key, value))
    def get_key_by_index(self, idx):
        return self.items_by_index[idx][0]
    def get_value_by_index(self, idx):
        key = self.get_key_by_index(idx)
        return self.items_by_key[key][1]
    def set_value_by_index(self, idx, value):
        key = self.items_by_index[idx][0]
        self[key] = value
    def __iter__(self):
        for key, value in self.items_by_index:
            yield key
```